# Create plugin in Visual Studio 2015 compatible with previous versions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

Is that possible to create plugin into Visual Studio 2015 which will be compatible and could be installed into different versions of Visual Studio 2013/2012/2010 ? How to do it if so ?

Update:
I know that I can create different versions of plugin/solutions  for/in different visual studios, but I was wondering if there is possibility to create one solution in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I created different solutions for/in different versions of Visual Studio with one shared library of course.Wondering if there is a way to have one solution and how to do it if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Visual Studio extension can support multiple versions of Visual Studio specifying them in the VSIX Manifest. Plus your extension should reference dlls present in all versions of Visual Studio, typically referencing the version of lowermost targeted VS version.

Comment: Thank you Sergey! I  will try to do that, I guess I can reference lowest versions via  Nuget